# Can I have Spring Event listener and Event Publisher as separate applications?

Tags: spring-boot

Can the event publisher application publish the event 24/7 and the listener application runs couple times a day to consume all the events?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to implement your use case. One is using JMS queues.
let say you create two spring boot application.

1. producer-app
2. consumer-app

producer-app will write the message to a queue whenever there are any messages coming to it. Below is one of the small code snippet which illustrate what I mean:-

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/object", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity writeObject(@RequestBody String requestPayload) {
    try {
        // This wil put the message to the queue.
        jmsTemplate.send("queue-name", mapper.writeValueAsString(requestPayload));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
 }
```

On the other hand, we have consumer-app which will do a poll at some regular interval and will read the message from the queue:-

```
@JmsListener(destination="queue-name",
    containerFactory="facotryName", id="id", concurrency="1-2")
public void receiveMessage(ActiveMQTextMessage message) throws Throwable 
{
 try {
     // read message here
 } catch (Throwable e) {

 }
}
```

This consumer app will have configured JmsListener which will start at the scheduled time. There is a bean JmsListenerEndpointRegistry available which you can leverage to pause and resume this.

Comment: Thanks. For your answer. I'm aware of various Queues. And it's simple to implement it in Queues. My question is specific to Spring events. Can it be implemented in Spring event or not?